# PHPMailer sending to multiple address

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send emails, i use this code to add the email address to send to:

```
$mail->addAddress("receipent@domain", "receipent");
```

it works for one email but does not work for multiple email.

i get an error saying

> You must provide at least one recipient email address.

Answer (score 2):

Just use it multiple times.

```
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');
```

Comment: @hasanurrahman Use above mentioned code as suggested by Larivact, It will help you

Answer (score 0):

Just call it one time for one address like

```
mail->addAddress("receipent1@domain", "receipent1");
mail->addAddress("receipent2@domain", "receipent2");
```